# How to assign a variable to colorsys output data

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

I was wondering if/how I could assign a variable to each outputted value from a colorsys conversion.

```
>>conversion = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(RC, GC, BC)
>>print(conversion)
>>#outputted data
>>(H,S,L)
```

Essentially I would like to use the outputted data in further variable dependent calculations using the H value the S value and the L value.

Sorry if my question is hard to understand I am new to python and not sure how to word my question without making it confusing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>>h_value, s_value, l_value = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(RC, GC, BC)
>>>print(h_value) 
>>>print(s_value) 
>>>print(l_value)
```

Comment: is it as simple as using commas to denote which value you would like to select?